# Using initialApolloState on a SSG NextJS site with dynamically created paths

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo

I've reconfigured my app based on [this official Vercel starter example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-apollo-server-and-client) and I've got it to the point where I have my data cached and set to `initialApolloState` from performing the queries in `getInitialProps`, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the extract the data from this object on each page.

My pages are dynamically created from `getStaticPaths` which queries a GraphQL API that is set up to query REST API endpoints. In my old configuration (which did not allow for SSG, which is why I had to reconfigure), the `getStaticProps` function used the page ID parameter to query data with that specific ID and get all the data needed for that page and set them to props. This new setup however, seems to set the data to the `initialApolloState` object with the ID attached to the object name itself.

For example, one of the prop objects is named `TourDossier:33887`, so I don't know how I'm supposed to extract any data from this object when it will have a unique name on each page. The page props have unique names on each page, as the ID is attached to the props themselves, which makes it impossible to access this data in a general way.

I suppose I'm just lost on how I'm supposed to extract data when using Apollo and SSG using the official example I listed above. The example is very simple and there seems to be another layer of complexity when using `getStaticPaths` and the ID parameter from the path in the `getStaticProps` query.

Any help or docs to read would be greatly appreciated.

edit: here is my dynamically created page(s) which use `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`

```
import { initializeApollo } from "../../apollo/client";
import NavBar from "../../widgets/NavBar";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import {
    GET_TOURS,
    GET_TOUR_DOSSIER,
    GET_ITIN_DOSSIER,
    GET_MAP_ROUTES,
    GET_MAP_ACTIVITIES,
    GET_MAP_TRANSPORT,
    GET_MAP_ACCOM,
} from "../../util/gql";
import TourMain from "../../widgets/TourMain";

const Tour = (props) => {
    const router = useRouter();

    // This returns 'undefined'.
    const data = useQuery(GET_TOUR_DOSSIER);

    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            // Passing these as props does not work since these objects
            // all have unique IDs based on the query (eg: tourDossier:33887)
            <TourMain
                tour={initialApolloState.tourDossier}
                itin={initialApolloState.itinDossier}
                mapRoutes={initialApolloState.mapRoutes}
                mapAccom={initialApolloState.mapAccom}
                mapActivities={initialApolloState.mapActivities}
                mapTransport={initialApolloState.mapTransport}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const apolloClient = initializeApollo();

    const tours = await apolloClient.query({
        query: GET_TOURS,
    });

    const paths = tours.data.tours.map((tour) => `/tours/${tour.id}`);

    // { fallback: false } means other routes should 404.
    return { paths, fallback: false };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const apolloClient = initializeApollo();

    const tourVars = { id: params.id };
    const tourDossier = await apolloClient.query({
        query: GET_TOUR_DOSSIER,
        variables: tourVars,
    });

    const itinVars = { id: tourDossier.data.tourDossier.itinerary[0].id };

    await apolloClient.query({
        query: GET_ITIN_DOSSIER,
        variables: itinVars,
    });

    await apolloClient.query({
        query: GET_MAP_ACCOM,
        variables: itinVars,
    });

    await apolloClient.query({
        query: GET_MAP_ACTIVITIES,
        variables: itinVars,
    });

    const mapTransport = await apolloClient.query({
        query: GET_MAP_TRANSPORT,
        variables: itinVars,
    });

    // Parse mapTransport array to coordinate string which can be consumed
    // by Mapbox Directions API.
    const coords = mapTransport.data.mapTransport.map((route) =>
        route
            .reduce(
                (str, place) =>
                    `${str};${place.coordinates[0]},${place.coordinates[1]}`,
                ""
            )
            .substring(1)
    );
    const routesVars = { coords };
    await apolloClient.query({
        query: GET_MAP_ROUTES,
        variables: routesVars,
    });

    // Pass tour and itinerary data to the page via props.
    return {
        props: {
            initialApolloState: apolloClient.cache.extract(),
        },
    };
}

export default Tour;
```

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be querying the cache in order to get page props or I'm somehow supposed to be able to extract the data from `initialApolloState` even though the objects all have unique names based on the ID of the query.

Comment: Post code snippet of page which has getStaticPaths and getStaticProps.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the code snippet.

Comment: I assume getStaticPaths and getStaticProps is working correctly? Problem is with retrieving data in Tour component?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Those two functions are working correctly. I don't know how I'm supposed to get the data from initialApolloState into my component. That object does not allow for it since it includes ID's in object names so I cannot access it programmatically.

Comment: One of possible problems is that you are using different query in component. In getStaticProps you are supplying variables, but in useQuery you do not. Can you modify useQuery to this const data = useQuery(GET_TOUR_DOSSIER, { variables: { id: router.query.id }});

Comment: Good point, that does indeed get my tour data. So am I correct in thinking that I need to basically mirror all of the queries in the component using useQuery? Is this the best practice for this sort of configuration?

Comment: Yes. I will post answer.

Comment: @user3366345 is it good practice to initialize apollo in both getStaticPaths and getStaticProps? I use the same code but to validate routes ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the same queries (including variables) in both `getStaticProps` and React component.

Apollo caches also on query AND variables, so query with different variables has different cache.

Change `useQuery` to include variables same as query in `getStaticProps`.

```
const data = useQuery(GET_TOUR_DOSSIER, {
  variables: { id: router.query.id } 
});
```